# PHP URL in query string using GET

Tags: php, html

I have a URL like:

```
http://www.google.com/test.html?d=1232&u=32
```

and I want to add it as a part of a GET query string like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.html?a=123&d=http://www.google.com/test.html?d=1232&u=32
```

Note the double "d" used.  I want the URL sent to be just a url and not be read for it's query string...

What is the best way to do this to avoid problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a url to a variable and have it be query-string safe by using urlencode() (http://us3.php.net/urlencode). So you could do:

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/index.html?a=123&d=' . urlencode('http://www.google.com/test.html?d=1232&u=32');
```

In this example the query-string var 'd' now houses all the contents of the second url. You will have to urldecode() it on the receiving end in order to extrapolate the data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/index.html?a=123&d='
       . urlencode('http://www.google.com/test.html?d=1232&u=32');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [urlencode()](http://us.php.net/urlencode) to put that in the URL without having it interfere with anything else you have in there.

Answer (score 1):

[URL-encode](http://php.net/urlencode) the second url:

```
http://mysite.com/index.html?a=123&d=<?php echo urlencode('http://google.com/etc..'); ?>
```